# How to iterate over a subset of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, indexing, iterator

How do I loop over a subset of a dataframe without reindexing. I want to loop over a subset of a dataframe. Because its the subset though its index is not ordered from 0 and on. In short the index for each record is not in any particular order. I'm using the df.loc[condition,'col'] to get my subset. I then need to iterate over that subset and assign a different value from a list to each record in the subset.

Comment: attach sample data and expected output

Comment: You likely don't need to loop here.

Comment: So I'm just try to iterate over a dataframe where the index is not in any particular order because its been shorted/filtered into a subset

Comment: Please create a [reprex].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your specific case as you didn't provide an example. As previously commented you likely don't need to iterate to conditionally change values. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["test1", "test2"])

df.loc[0] = [1,1]
df.loc[1] = [1,2]
df.loc[2] = [1,3]
df.loc[3] = [2,4]
df.loc[4] = [2,5]
df.loc[5] = [2,6]

def function(subDF):
    return subDF + 1

df.loc[df.test1==2, "test2"] = function(df.loc[df.test1==2, "test2"])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   test1  test2
0      1      1
1      1      2
2      1      3
3      2      5
4      2      6
5      2      7
```

Comment: So I have a df with 2 col 1 is 1-5 and the other col is blank. I want to fill the blank col with a series of numbers 1-3 but I want to place 1-3 parallel to 2-4 in the first col. I wanted to loop through my selection (2-4 in the 1st col in this case) and assign in order 1-3 to the 3 blank cell in the second col

Comment: In this case you can use my solution (1) with:
`ex_con = (ex_df.x2 >= 2) & (ex_df.x2 <= 4)`
 and `ex_l = [1, 2, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to select a piece of your data frame (`ex_df`) based on a condition (`ex_con`) and replace the values of one of the columns with values from a list (`ex_l`). There are some possible cases:

1. You already know the size of the replacement and `ex_l` is a fixed list with arbitrary values (which is probably a sign there is a better approach);

```
import pandas as pd

ex_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'x2': [-11, -12, -13, 14, -15, -16, 17, 18, 19, -20]
    }
)

ex_con = (ex_df.x1 >= 5) & (ex_df.x2 < 0)

ex_l = [99, 357, 7]

solution_df = ex_df.copy()

solution_df.loc[ex_con, 'x2'] = ex_l

print(solution_df)
```

2. You want to replace the values applying a function (`ex_f`) based on the values of the data-frame;

```
import pandas as pd

ex_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'x2': [-11, -12, -13, 14, -15, -16, 17, 18, 19, -20]
    }
)

ex_con = (ex_df.x1 >= 5) & (ex_df.x2 < 0)

def ex_f(row):
    return row.x2*10

solution_df = ex_df.copy()

solution_df.loc[ex_con, 'x2'] = solution_df.loc[ex_con, ]\
    .apply(ex_f, axis = 1)

print(solution_df)
```

3. You want to replace the values applying a mapping (`ex_map`) based on the values of the data-frame;

```
import pandas as pd

ex_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'x2': [-11, -12, -13, 14, -15, -16, 17, 18, 19, -20]
    }
)

ex_con = (ex_df.x1 >= 5) & (ex_df.x2 < 0)

ex_map = {
    -13: 0,
    -15: 1,
    -16: 2,
    -17: 3,
    -18: 4,
    -19: 999,
    -20: 99}

solution_df = ex_df.copy()

solution_df.loc[ex_con, "x2"] = solution_df.loc[ex_con, "x2"].replace(ex_map)

print(solution_df)
```

4. You want to replace the values that match the condition for a constant (`ex_c`):

```
import pandas as pd

ex_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'x2': [-11, -12, -13, 14, -15, -16, 17, 18, 19, -20]
    }
)

ex_con = (ex_df.x1 >= 5) & (ex_df.x2 < 0)

ex_c = 0

solution_df = ex_df.copy()

solution_df.loc[ex_con, 'x2'] = ex_c

print(solution_df)
```

5. (!!! WARNING: BAD PRACTICE !!!) All the previous solutions avoid looping the pandas data frame, but in case you really want to loop the section of the data frame and replace the values based on an arbitrary list:

```
import pandas as pd

ex_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'x1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        'x2': [-11, -12, -13, 14, -15, -16, 17, 18, 19, -20]
    }
)

ex_con = (ex_df.x1 >= 5) & (ex_df.x2 < 0)

ex_l = [99, 357, 7]

solution_df = ex_df.copy()

for ind, row in enumerate(solution_df.loc[ex_con].index):
    solution_df.loc[row, 'x2'] = ex_l[ind]

print(solution_df)
```